# How to test the CPU with a simple C++ program

Tags: c++, cpu, benchmarking, timing

In my opinion, I have two ways to do this:
One is to use a loop:

```
t1 = getTime();
for(int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
{}
t2 = getTime();
```

And now I can check `t2 - t1`.

The other is to create many threads, each thread does the same loop above.

I don't know if the second way is better than the first one.

Or maybe there are better ways to test CPU?

Comment: test the CPU for what?

Comment: @jaket I think it's poor wording. It looks like they are curious about timing the execution of code.

Comment: A modern optimizer will throw away your entire loop. And as @jaket says, what do you want to achieve with this test? How do you “test a bike”? Do you lift up the rear wheel an spin the pedals with one hand and if the wheel revolves fast, conclude that the bike must be good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop does nothing and will be optimized out by every reasonable compiler.

To get reasonable benchmark results, you'll have to solve (somewhat) reasonable problems, like calculating many digits of pi, finding big primes or whatever task(s) you want to base your definition of *fast* on, with good implementations of efficient algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

```
t1 = getTime();
int n=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    n += i;
t2 = getTime();
cout << n << endl;
```

Comment: a) This will overflow `int` on the most common platforms at least. b) Still get optimized to a O(1) operation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a585579144bf54eb

Comment: b) checked it with g++ -O3; at least g++ is not that smart

Comment: a) That's undefined behavior, that's what. A compiler can make this into anything it wants.

Comment: a) no, integer overflow is NOT undefined behaviour.

Comment: Bet you 50 bucks it is.

Comment: No thanks.  But see http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/ .

Comment: Ah cplusplus.com. Good thing C++ is standardized: *"If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined."* 5/4 in N4140 Fortunately, there is a [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: The compiler will produce the integer addition command. It cannot produce anything else (unless it is smart enough to calculate n*(n+1)/2, or do loop unrolling etc.)  The integer addition is performed modulo 2**32 (or whatever the size of integer).

Comment: @user31264 But it's still undefined behavior and the compiler can produce something completely different (and possibly invalid) in certain situations. You can't rely on the compiler doing the right thing. It could optimize out everything after the overflow, for example. Or crash.

Comment: just use a smaller upper boundary for i.. then it should be fine. the loop will not be optimized away since you ouput the result n.